# Realize slider on js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anybody help me to realize this slider (https://codepen.io/zuraizm/pen/vGDHl) on js!  I can't understand that code:

```
function moveLeft() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: + slideWidth
    }, 5200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
};
```

Help me please!

Comment: what are you trying to ask ? what do you mean by **realize**

Comment: I want write this code on js. don't use jquery. but I don't know why this works.
function moveLeft() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: + slideWidth
    }, 5200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
};
do you know it? can you help me! my js level is bad but i try study it every day.

Comment: Well, you need to have some basic understanding of jquery functions, how they work. Have you read the documentation for the [**`animate()`**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function before trying to translate/implement in javascript.

Comment: yes i read it. but i can't write it on js. i wrote this without animation, it's bad for me

Comment: do you know how write this animation on js? help me please.  i try to write it two days.

Comment: no one will write the code for you until you show some effort from your end